# How to auto mount a specific USB drive (and only that) with specific options whenever connected?

Tags: debian

I want to set up a backup system (e.g. backuppc) for my laptop to use an external usb drive.

Ideally I would like the system to recognise *that* usb drive, when plugged in, and mount it always at the same mount point, with appropriate mount options, even when there is no user logged in (i.e. no gnome running).

I would also like this setup to NOT interfere with normal gnome (or other desktop) automounting of any other device.

Possibly, I would like to add a post-mount script to start the backup system and a pre-umount one to stop the backup system.
In this way, triggering a backup would be as easy as plugging in the backup disk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a file like `/etc/udev/rules.d/custom.rules` with this inside:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="YOUR_DEVICE_LABEL", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/script.sh /dev/%k
```

Update `/etc/fstab` like so:

```
LABEL=YOUR_DEVICE_LABEL /mnt/YOUR_DEVICE_LABEL auto your,mount,options 0 0
```

Your script `/usr/local/sbin/script.sh` will receive the full device name as first argument. So it just needs to run `mount "$1"` to mount the drive.

Of course, you can run any pre- and post-mount stuff in your script as well.

If you want GNOME to ignore the device, you can again use udev to export a special variable like:

```
ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```